# Meaning of Profile Login IP

Tags: profile, login

Our company has multiple org, I just took possession one of those. I saw the following IP range in Profile Login IP range: 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.**254**. Is there a reasonable purpose to have that setting. Anyway any IP address hit that range. Or this's a Salesforce trick made for some purpose? I believe it is safe to remove it. Is that correct?

Comment: Interesting, because omitting `255.255.255.255` seems like more of a gimmick than anything; that's a reserved address, so you wouldn't observe a login coming from that address. Is there a former admin you could ask? I'd be curious as well

Comment: Perhaps forcing users to use IPv4 as opposed to IPv6?  This is purely speculative though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With that IP range users can connect from anywhere around the world. It is always a best practice to restrict to your own IP ranges.
Usually some companies use it only on SandBox'es since they keep on refreshing. But for Production environment this has to be kept safe and potentially block users from accessing else where. By doing so you are adhering to your companies security policies. This is a bigger security key when it comes to integration.